# Regex - Need to match string if first following exact string has itself a directly following string

Tags: .net, regex

I`ve got a regex problem, here is a simplified version:

I want to select the value 'pie' of the first match in the string is 'friend', which isn`t directly followd by the string ' angry'.

Here is what I got:

**regex**

`\b(pie)\b(?!(.|\n|\r|\r\n)*?friend[ ]angry)`

It goes all the way down to the last match of 'friend angry', but I want to stop the processing after the first 'friend', and check if its directly followed by ' angry'

**string:**

`pie
jibberish jibberish
friend
pie 
friend
pie 
jibberish friend angry
pie 
friend`

I`v got a regex which does almost what I want, but that one stops at a character, not a string:

`\b(pie)\b(?![^<]*([<]/h\d))`
This one checks if the string is directly contained in a h2 tag, but I want to match on a string, not a character

My regex fu is really rusty, I think this should be possible...

Link to [regextest](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb(pie)%5Cb(%3F!(.%7C%5Cr)*%3Ffriend%5B%20%5Dangry)&i=pie%0D%0Ajibberish%20jibberish%0D%0Afriend%0D%0Apie%20%0D%0Afriend%0D%0Apie%20%0D%0Ajibberish%20friend%20angry%0D%0Apie%20%0D%0Afriend&o=s)

**UPDATE**

The regex should match pie.  The matched value shouldnt be matched if it finds the string "friend angry" after pie, but should be matched if it finds friend. 
Pie should also be matched, if friend isnt found at all in the following string, until the next pie

TEST INPUT:
pie jibberish
pie
pie friend pie friend angry
pie

Every pie should be matched, except the third one, because it is followed by friend, but this friend isn`t directly followed by angry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I assume you have parsed the string out from HTML code and you are working with plain text.**

To match *the shortest window* between two strings is a tempered greedy token (that can be unrolled).

```
(?s)\bpie\b(?:(?!\b(?:friend|pie)\b).)*friend[ ]angry
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iS5rV8/2)

The `(?:(?!\bfriend\b).)*` subpattern matches any symbol (note the inline singleline modifier `(?s)` that makes a dot match a newline) that is not starting the `friend` or `pie` character sequences.

Note that `[ ]` can be replaced with `\p{Zs}` to match all *horizontal* Unicode whitespace characters.

To also avoid matching `pie` that is not directly followed by `friend`, you need to use a negative lookahead *after* you consume all the characters after `pie` before a `friend angry`:

```
(?s)(?>\bpie\b(?:(?!\b(?:friend|pie)\b).)*)(?!friend(?![ ]angry))(?:friend[ ]angry)?
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3E%5Cbpie%5Cb(%3F%3A(%3F!%5Cb(%3F%3Afriend%7Cpie)%5Cb).)%2A)(%3F!friend(%3F!%5B%20%5Dangry))(%3F%3Afriend%5B%20%5Dangry)%3F&i=pie%0D%0Apie%0D%0Apie%20friend%0D%0Apie%20friend%20angry%0D%0Apie&o=s)

The `(?>...)` construct is an *atomic group* that prevents backtracking. That means, the `(?!friend(?![ ]angry))` lookahead is only executed once all the `\bpie\b(?:(?!\b(?:friend|pie)\b).)*` symbols are matched. The negative lookahead `(?!friend(?![ ]angry))` fails the match if there is no `friend` that is not directly followed by a space + `angry`.

Comment: Thanks! Almost there! Except there is one more requirement which I wasnt clear about, sorry. The extra requirement is that if the string **friend** isnt found, the pie match is always valid. You`re assumptions where right btw.

Comment: So, what exactly should be matched in the provided string? Right now, it is `pie 
jibberish friend angry`. Do you mean [`\bpie\b(?:(?!\b(?:friend|pie)\b).)*(?:friend[ ]angry)?`](https://regex101.com/r/iS5rV8/3)?

Comment: The output for the provided string was perfect, but the provided string wasn`t a complete usecase, im sorry.

The regex should match pie (cleanest would be this will be the only one returned, but that is not 100% necessary)

The matched value shouldn`t be matched if it finds the string friend angry, but should be matched if it finds friend.

The information I forgot to mention, is that pie should also be matched, if friend isn`t found at all in the following string, until the next pie (my test input didn`t make this clear, excuse me)

Comment: So, for the test string:
pie  
pie  
pie  
friend  
pie  
friend angry  
pie  
  
  Every pie should be matched, except the third one, because it is followed by friend, but this friend isn`t directly followed by angry

Comment: Please add the test string and expected result to the question

Comment: pie  
jibberish  
pie  
pie  
friend  
pie  
friend angry  
pie

Comment: Every pie should be matched, except the third one, because it is followed by friend, but this friend isn`t directly followed by angry

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments, but the newline isnt working here for comments :-(

Comment: Try [`(?s)(?>\bpie\b(?:(?!\b(?:friend|pie)\b).)*)(?!friend(?![ ]angry))(?:friend[ ]angry)?`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3e%5cbpie%5cb(%3f%3a(%3f!%5cb(%3f%3afriend%7cpie)%5cb).)*)(%3f!friend(%3f!%5b+%5dangry))(%3f%3afriend%5b+%5dangry)%3f&i=pie%0d%0apie%0d%0apie+friend%0d%0apie+friend+angry%0d%0apie&o=s).

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! I`ll update my question to make things more usable for somebody with the same question. You`re very quick, quess you have a lot of experience with regex :-)

Comment: I will add this regex with explanation to the answer once I have more time.